# Best configuration for TinyMCE for XML for Flash

Tags: php, xml, flash, tinymce, jquery-tools

Can you tell me the best configuration for TinyMCE to make a XML file for flash? The problem are the carriage returns. I've browsed the TinyMCE forums and didn't find anything useful for that.

Can you help me with this little problem?

Thanks in advance,
Elkas